# Error when using moment.max with the results of a mongoDB query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

I am working on a nodeJS application that inserts documents into a mongoDB collection. The document has a createdAt field that records the time of creation. I also have a function that logs the most recent match of a query to the console.

Code:

```
function getResult(player){
  let timeList = [];
  MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    if(err){
     console.log(err);
    }
    else{
     let count = db.collection('PokeBook').count({ 'player1': player });   //count function returns a promise
      count.then((val) => {
        db.collection('PokeBook').find({ 'player1': player }).forEach((doc) => {
          timeList.push(doc.createdAt);
          console.log(doc.createdAt);
          if(val===timeList.length){
            myEmitter.emit('full', timeList);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}    

//code for the emitter:
myEmitter.on('full', (arr) => {
  console.log('full emitted');
  console.log(moment.max(arr));
});
```

the code returns an error saying moments[i].isValid is not a function. Commenting the moment.max line of code results in successfully logging "full emitted" to the console.

Any advice on why this happens and how to fix this will be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment.max()` expects an array of `Moment` objects, but `doc.createdAt` is (probably) a regular `Date` object. You can try to replace:

```
timeList.push(doc.createdAt);
```

with:

```
timeList.push(moment(doc.createdAt));
```

so `arr` would be an array of `Moment` objects.

Alternatively, you can implement `max` yourself w/o using moment, assuming `doc.createdAt` is either `Date` or `Number`:

```
console.log(arr.sort()[arr.length-1]);
```

Comment: It returns a different error this time: locale.longDateFormat is not a function.

Comment: What is the `typeof` of `doc.createdAt`? In addition, I've update my answer with another option.

Comment: They were moment objects. I changed my code to generate Date objects and then used your first method, which worked well. Thank you! :)